# Why don't we commonly use bra-ket notation in acoustics and vibration?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, acoustics, notation, linear-algebra

I have a background in acoustics and do more and more of quantum mechanics.

**I wonder why don't we use more often the bra-ket notation in acoustics and vibrations like in quantum mechanics?**

In modal analysis, we deal everyday with Hilbert spaces, inner products and linear algebra so I think that it would make sens to use the notation in the same manner. Is it because the notion of state vector is less important in those contexts?

Comment: It is vastly more likely to be due to legacy. The modal analysis of acoustics predated the quantum theory's popularisation of Hilbert spaces, matrices, and other such fancy tools by centuries. You should also note that, while bra-ket notation is really convenient and helpful, it would however, present itself as a barrier-to-entry for a beginner, especially one who is not coming from the quantum physics perspective. Sound engineers and musicians coming into acoustics should not be prevented from understanding this by mere notational change. However, your question is better on HSM.SE than here.

Comment: It would bring lots of confusion and little benefit, just like in quantum theory.